# Group Sum not adding a row in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I want to do a Group Sum total of OrderQTY per Work Order(WO). At times, I can have multiple rows per Work order because there can be several people on that job sequence per WO. However, for the total I am looking to sum only (Row 1)OrderQTY per Work Order

Example

Group: PARTID - Cog123

### WorkID   OrderQTY    Seq

**Row 1**   WO1                   **20**                                1

Row 2   WO1                     20                                2

**Row 1**   WO2                   **20**                              1

**Row 1**   WO3                  **20**                            1

I used "Running Total Fields Function"

Summary
"Field to summarize" = OrderQTY

Evaluate 
"Use a Formula" = previous(WorkID)<>WorkID

Reset
"On change of group" PartID

However the total I get is 40. I need the answer to be 60. It's misses a row. How do I correct this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Evaluate should be set to "On change of field" for WorkID, not the formula you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the running total to evaluate on change of workID then you will get correct answer.